# How to make the variable in the class act like reference value?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Now i am creating a class, the class have the variable, the following is the example(just an example dont too serious to it)

```
class NewGroupCell2TableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UITextFieldDelegate {

var customSearchBarController:CustomSearchController!
@IBOutlet weak var sortByButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var hashTagTextField: UITextField!
var testingString:String!
```

}

However when i am creating this class, i passing in the value of the variable into the class. So it would be like

```
let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewGroupCell2TableViewCell
                cell2.customSearchBarController = customSearchController
                cell2.testingString = testingString
```

However, on the class which calling the NewGroupCell2TableViewCell, there is a testingString variable, what i am expect it, when the event in the NewGroupCell2TableViewCell changing value of the testingString, the outer class variable of testingString can be changes when the event in the NewGroupCell2TableViewCell changes the testingString value. How i am able to let the variable reference with the inner class and the outer class??

Note that inout function only able to use on the function class.

Comment: Strings in Swift are value types (structs), so your two string variables are not references to a single object

Comment: the thing is, how i am able to reference it?

Comment: There are a couple of solutions, none of them particularly good. You could create a delegate method on the VC + a protocol, and conform the cell to the protocol then call the delegate method in the setter to update the value in the VC (unpleasant because it adds a side effect to the setter). Or use NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Or you could create a class wrapping the string and assign that, I suppose - that's probably the simplest.

Comment: i will try to use the delegate